# How to merge nodes that have the same value for name property in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I just push text corpus into Neo4j database. When I execute `MATCH (n) RETURN n` Cypher query, it returns multiple nodes with the same name. how can I merge these nodes as one?

[image: Graph Visualization of my DB]
[nodes having same name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThrdU.png)

Comment: Have you only `name` property in your nodes?

Comment: Also, can exists more than 2 nodes with the same name? For example, 3 nodes with `name = Java`.

Comment: yes, nodes have only name property and there exist more than one nodes with the same name

Comment: more than TWO nodes with the same name?

Comment: I made a mistake in the previous comment, sorry. I need know if you can have more than 2 nodes with the same name.

Comment: yes https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThrdU.png

Comment: AkhilTC - Let me know if the answer I provided has solved your issue. Thanks.

Comment: Bruno Peres - I tried  the query you suggested but the issue was not solve

Comment: I tried the query you suggested but shows error message  Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureRegistrationFailed

apoc.refactor.mergeNodes is unavailable because it is sandboxed and has dependencies outside of the sandbox. Sandboxing is controlled by the dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted setting. Only unrestrict procedures you can trust with access to database internals.

Comment: AkhilTC - This is because APOC procedures should be installed. Take a look in the [installation section](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_installation).

Answer (score 6):

Your name values have different values because of upper and lower case letters ("Java" and "java" are different).

I reproduced your scenario creating a sample data set:

```
CREATE (n1:Node {name : "Java"}),
(n2:Node {name : "Java"}),
(n3:Node {name : "java"}),
(n1)-[:TYPE]->(),
(n1)-[:TYPE]->(),
(n1)-[:TYPE]->(),
(n2)-[:TYPE]->(),
(n2)-[:TYPE]->(),
(n3)-[:TYPE]->()
```

The above query will produce this graph:

[image: Sample graph]

To merge all "Java" nodes you can use the [APOC Procedure](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) `apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(nodes)`. Running the following query:

```
MATCH (n:Node)
// using toLower function to group nodes with the same name but 
// different cases (eg Java, java, javA)
WITH toLower(n.name) as name, collect(n) as nodes
// passing the nodes collection to mergeNodes APOC procedure
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(nodes) yield node
RETURN *
```

Will update your graph to:

[image: Updated graph]

Comment: I am mapping state transitions in APIs using Neo4j. My Relationship also has a property. The relationship is the count of the response codes. I want to merge them all together including the property.
(API_1)-[:CALLS {'2xx': 1}] -> (API_2)
(API_1)-[:CALLS {'4xx': 1}] -> (API_2)
(API_1)-[:CALLS {'2xx': 2}] -> (API_2)
(API_1)-[:CALLS {'4xx': 3}] -> (API_2)

Desired merging result:
(API_1)-[:CALLS {'2xx': 3, '4xx': 4}] -> (API_2)
Is this possible, I am not sure